# How is Aurora serverless different than aurora with autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

How is Aurora serverless different than aurora with autoscaling / what aurora already did with expanding capacity automatically as your data gew? The explanation of Aurora serverless I found said it automatically scales capacity... that sounds like auto scaling to me.

Answer (score 2):

**AWS Aurora Autoscaling** works by adding more number of reader instances to the Aurora Cluster and when it has to scale down, it remove the reader instances. Important here, this process takes some time to spin up the new reader instances as well to remove them, so you should configure your autoscaling policy accordingly. Autoscaling only add read capacity to Aurora Cluster.

[More information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html)

**AWS Aurora Serverless** continuously tracks utilization of resources such as CPU, memory, and network and scale any writer or reader instance. AWS Aurora Serverless scales instantly to hundreds of thousands of transactions in a fraction of a second, it adjusts capacity in fine-grained increments to provide the right amount of database resources that the application needs. Aurora Serverles increase write and read capacity to Aurora Cluster.

[More information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html)